# Use of infix operator hack in production code (Python)

Tags: python

What is your opinion of using the [infix operator hack](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122-infix-operators/) in production code? Issues:

- The effect this will have on speed.
- The potential for a clashes with an object with these operators already defined. This seems particularly dangerous with generic code that is intended to handle objects of any type.

It is a shame that this isn't built in - it really does improve readability

Comment: Ew. Ew ew ew. But that's just me.

Comment: I think it's awesome that python is expressive enough to let you do things like this.  I think it's even more awesome that the python community is smart enough not to use this.  It improves readability on the toy code level, but it kills readability if used in a real code base, because the real operators are doing unexpected things which aren't even particularly clear when you look them up.  And as you pointed out yourself, can easily be broken.  (tl;dr—what Ignacio said.)

Comment: "it really does improve readability"?  Really?  How?  Could you post some example code that has this "improvement" by adding bizarre, non-standard, unknown syntax.

Comment: @Lott: Look at the samples provided in the link

Comment: @Casebash: I did.  They seem to be perfectly incomprehensible.   Since they're buried in comments with almost no working code around them, perhaps it's unfair to simply look at the comment to judge.  I was hoping you had something that was a more complete example showing how this was an improvement over the alternative standard Python syntax.

Comment: @Lott See this question which is about addition and multiplication of tuples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802020/overloading-to-support-tuples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be measurably slower than more Pythonic code, fragile (e.g. in the way you suggest), and baffling to every expert Python programmer that comes upon such code for the first time.

If you want to turn Python into one of the very few languages that allow user-defined infix operators (such as Haskell), you're better off designing a way to alter the syntax dynamically for the purpose, implement it as a patch to Python's parser, and start lobbying for it -- if it improves readability as much as you say, then it shouldn't be that hard to get Guido's approval for a clean, easy-to-explain implementation (if Guido, as I suspect, should sternly reject it instead, then you may want to ponder who's a better judge of language readability: you, or the designer of one of the most readable widespread languages? but I can't channel Guido, that's the **tim**bot's job;-).

Comment: 1) Isn't there a Python language freeze atm?
2) I think the Python syntax is running out of unused characters, so adding such a feature would almost certainly break code. There *might* have been a chance if the change was proposed before 3.x, but I don't think its likely at all at the moment.

Comment: @casebash, (1) yes for now, but not forever, (2) `'?'` is still free, backquote is free in 3 (was taken in 2), and there's a _lot_ of Unicode punctuation available (since Python 3 goes by utf8) if we need more. So I don't think the chance is any less (or more) now than it was during Python 3's design phase.

Comment: @Casebash, depends on your system, keyboard and settings -- on a Mac, for many popular Unicode glyphs, it's → quite ♥ easy indeed, be it in ☂ rain or ☀ sunshine...☆★✮✯...

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion this would not be a great idea in production code: the biggest problem with it is that it totally non-standard and will probably leave non-familiar readers wondering where this novel syntax has suddenly sprung from.

I think you should prefer clarity rather than succinctness in general - Python is not C!