# Overloading + to support tuples

Tags: python, operator-overloading, tuples

I'd like to be able to write something like this in python:

```
a = (1, 2)
b = (3, 4)
c = a + b # c would be (4, 6)
d = 3 * b # d would be (9, 12)
```

I realize that you can overload operators to work with custom classes, but is there a way to overload operators to work with pairs?

Of course, such solutions as

```
c = tuple([x+y for x, y in zip(a, b)])
```

do work, but, let aside performance, they aren't quite as pretty as overloading the `+` operator.

One can of course define `add` and `mul` functions such as

```
def add((x1, y1), (x2, y2)):
    return (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)

def mul(a, (x, y)):
    return (a * x, a * y)
```

but still being able to write `q * b + r` instead of `add(times(q, b), r)` would be nicer.

Ideas?

**EDIT**: On a side note, I realize that since `+` currently maps to tuple concatenation, it might be unwise to redefine it, even if it's possible. The question still holds for `-` for example =)

Comment: On a side note, a generator expression (`tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(a,b))`) saves the creation of the unneeded list.

Comment: True; not exactly pretty yet, though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In contrast to Ruby, you can't change the behaviour of built-in types in Python.  All you can do is create a new type *derived* from a built-in type.  Literals will still create the built-in type, though.

Probably the best you can get is

```
class T(tuple):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return T(x + y for x, y in zip(self, other))
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return T(other * x for x in self)
a = T((1, 2))
b = T((3, 4))
c = a + b # c would be (4, 6)
d = 3 * b # d would be (9, 12)
```

Comment: s/porbably/probably ;) Thanks!

Comment: Side note: using complex numbers works too; don't know how it's implemented under the hood, and whether it would save performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can inherit a class from `tuple` and overload its `__add__` method. Here's a very simplistic example:

```
class mytuple(tuple):
    def __add__(self, other):
        assert len(self) == len(other)
        return tuple([x + y for x, y in zip(self, other)])

mt = mytuple((5, 6))
print mt + (2, 3)  # prints (7, 9)
```

I wouldn't recommend this approach though, because tuples weren't really designed for this purpose. If you want to perform numeric computations, just use `numpy`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify types defined in C, so you would need to create all new types for this. Or you could just use NumPy, which already has types that support this.

Answer (score 2):

Using python complex numbers is definitely one way to do it, if not extremely pretty.

```
a = 1 + 2j
b = 3 + 4j
c = a + b # c would be 4 + 6j
d = 3 * b # d would be 9 + 12j
```

That saves the definition of an extra class.

Also, expanding on previous answers,

```
class T(tuple):
    def __add__((x, y), (x1, y1)):
        return T((x+x1, y+y1))
    def __rmul__((x, y), other):
        return T((other * x, other * y))
```

would improve performance, at the cost of restraining the implementation to pairs.

Comment: This may not be extremely pretty, but there's no reason for it to be ugly, either. The only real problem is cosmetic: pairs are presented as 1 + 2j instead of something like Pair(1,2). But subclassing complex requires only the __str__ and __repr__ methods to overridden to get something more appealing.

Answer (score 2):

There is the famous [infix operator hack](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122-infix-operators/) that would allow you to do soemthing like this:

```
x = Infix(lambda a,b:tuple([x+y for x, y in zip(a, b)]))
y = Infix(lambda a,b:tuple([a*y for y in b]))

c = a |x| b # c would be (4, 6)
d = 3 |y| b # d would be (9, 12)
```

That would hide the generator expressions and be applicable to tuples of all lengths, at the expense of "weird" pseudo-operators `|x|` and `|y|`.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own class and implement `__mul__, __add__` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.array` to get all you need.